# How could we decompose anticommutator of representation matrices for a Lie algebra?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

For commutator, we know that $[T^a,T^b]=if^{abc}T^c$, where $f^{abc}$ is the structure constant. But is there a similar formula for $\{T^a, T^b\}$?

Thank you.

Comment: What is your definition of the anti-commutator?

Comment: [Yes and no](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/221851/the-anticommutator-of-sun-generators/362009#362009).